# Word VBA ignore all

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to scan an entire Word document and ignore all spelling errors.

I found this line but it is specific to a certain string.

```
ActiveDocument.Styles("Test").NoProofing = True
```

How do I do it for all errors?

Comment: Can you just go to File -> Options -> Proofing and check "Hide spelling errors in this document only"?

Comment: I guess I could, but I would like to be able to automize this for multiple documents in a loop.

Comment: Then maybe try this: `ActiveDocument.ShowGrammaticalErrors = False
    ActiveDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = False` on each iteration of your documents.

Comment: That worked great, thank you

Comment: There is a difference between hiding errors and accepting them. Not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on each iteration of the documents:

```
ActiveDocument.ShowGrammaticalErrors = False 
ActiveDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = False
```